# What are the conditions and qualifications for making blogs?

Tags: support, blog, meta-reputation

I am going to publish my mathematical researches and efforts on stack-exchange as blog ...
But I don't see the **Create new blog entry** button for myself ! may you guide me ?

Comment: If you mean [the on-site blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/) you should ask [in the blog chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14206/the-blog-room). Some instructions are given [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13903/11619). Your blog idea needs to be approved and your post will be reviewed and edited before it is approved and scheduled to appear.